# Error creating bean in maven spring, hibernate project

Tags: java, mysql, spring, eclipse, hibernate

I am getting bean creating error for building online site. Here is the stack trace error message details:

> Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'adminService'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'adminService': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'adminDAO'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'adminDAO': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/main-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
> service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutow

Here is my Main-Servlet.xml code:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.simplilearn" />
    <beans:bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
         <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"></beans:property>
         <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}"></beans:property>
          <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></beans:property>
          <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
          <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.simplilearn.entity"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="configLocation">
            <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Here is web.xml code

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
          <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/main-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/main-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
 
</web-app>
 application properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
 jdbc properties
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb?useSSL=false
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root

Here is my hibernate.cfg file
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
Here is the pom file
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SportyShoes</groupId>
  <artifactId>SportyShoes</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Section7LEP Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  
    <!-- JBoss repository for Hibernate --> 
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
   <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>5.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
  </properties>
 
 
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
      
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     
    <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
             
    <dependency> 
       <groupId>log4j</groupId> 
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId> 
       <version>1.2.16</version> 
     </dependency> 
      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.guicedee.services/sl4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.guicedee.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>sl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13.5</version>
</dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
  
  
     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
     
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
         
   <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.23</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency> 
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
       <version>1.2</version> 
 </dependency>
 


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Section7LEP2</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
             <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                     <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>        
                 </configuration>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-war</id> 
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
         

        </plugins>
  </build>
  
  
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

it work for me

```
enter code here


<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.24.RELEASE</version> 
  </dependency>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.24.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency> 
<dependency>    
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>        
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version> 
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
         <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
 </dependency>
    
    <dependency>    
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0.Final</version> 
</dependency>
    <dependency>    
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: You focus on the one which is necessary to answer the question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).